# How to search through my answers

Tags: feature-request, support

Is there any way to grep through my answers and get at them programmaticaly?

I am trying to find a link in someone else's answer to a question that i referenced when answering a question.

Comment: +1 I'm so glad you asked this question... up till now, I've been slowly paging through my answers trying to find certain things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `user:me` and `is:answer` as parts of your search parameters.

Comment: @Flexo - Possibly, though the last sentence suggests that the OP is talking about an answer they had given for someone else' question.